# UWP ApplicationData LocalSettings

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I am working on UWP, I want to store paths somewhere, and I found ApplicationData.LocalSettings can do it.
But I got an error when I stored the share folder path through it because of the **\** and I don't know why. Is there any good solution to it?
Here is the code,just simple:

```
var path = @"\\192.168.1.1\test";

ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.Keys.Contains<string>(path);
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[path] = xxx;
```

The contains function and add function also throw COMException

Comment: BTW, UWP is **not** WPF.  (tag removed)

Comment: You are using "path" as a key not value; and the string your path contains does not seem to be a valid key for the settings collection.

Comment: Yes,I use the "path" as a key, but shouldn't it be a string?Why it throws the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UWP ApplicationData LocalSettings

We could reproduce this problem, it looks "\" char is not support but not "", for this scenario, the better way is using "path" string as key to replace path value-key. And I will report this problem.

ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["path"] = xxxx;

Or replace the header  `\\` with empty.

```
var path = @"192.168.1.1\test";
```

Comment: Yes, the issue is "\\",maybe because of coding problem,it becomes "".So there is no way to handle it?Then maybe I will try json to store it.

Comment: as @Lorenzo said, you could use other symbol to replace "//", and use "//" to replace retrieve value.  and you could also post this problem with windows feed back hub app.

Comment: Fine, thanks a lot.I will try to report it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. LocalSettings cannot use *path* as a key since it contains the **\** symbol.

For example,

```
        String path = @"&&192.168.1.1&test"; // I replaced every \ with &
        ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[path] = "your string";
```

will save `your string` correctly.

Comment: Yes, this way can be passed.But normally "\" shoule seem like a string, why it throws the error.